# Sign in PHP script add type of user superadmin,admin and user

Tags: php

I have Sign-in script PHP single user working fine. But I want to add sign-in multiuser like superadmin, admin and user. I have need please help me...

**I have need login_type full code**

> Sign-in login_type "superadmin" header location "superadmin.php"
>
> Sign-in login_type "admin" header location "admin.php"
>
> Sign-in login_type "user" header location "user.php"

**Sign-in php script here**

```
     <?php

       $username = $password = "";
        $username_err = $password_err = "";
        if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){

    if(empty(trim($_POST["username"]))){
        $username_err = "Please enter username.";
    } else{
        $username = trim($_POST["username"]);
    }

    if(empty(trim($_POST["password"]))){
        $password_err = "Please enter your password.";
    } else{
        $password = trim($_POST["password"]);
    }

    if(empty($username_err) && empty($password_err)){
        $sql = "SELECT user_id, username, password FROM login WHERE username = ?";

        if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql)){
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param_username);

            $param_username = $username;

            if(mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
                mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

                if(mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt) == 1){                    

                    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $user_id, $username, $hashed_password);
                    if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                        if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                            session_start();
                            $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                            $_SESSION["user_id"] = $user_id;
                            $_SESSION["username"] = $username;


                            header("location: index.php");

                        } else{
                            $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                        }
                    }
                } else{
                    $username_err = "No account found with that username.";
                }
            } else{
                echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
            }
        }

        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    mysqli_close($conn);
}
    ?>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines. In its current form, this question does *not* meet their guidelines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have maintain a separate column in table like `login_type` for every user and store 1 for superadmin, 2 for admin, 3 for others ...etc,

```
    $sql = "SELECT user_id, username,type_login password FROM login WHERE username = ?";
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $user_id, $username, $type_login, $hashed_password);
```

Edit above two lines and this `if($type_login==1){`  check below

```
             if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)){
                    if(password_verify($password, $hashed_password)){
                        session_start();
                        $_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
                        $_SESSION["user_id"] = $user_id;
                        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
                        if( $type_login==1){
                            header("location: superadmin.php");
                        }elseif($type_login==2){
                            header("location: admin.php");                                
                        }elseif($type_login==3){
                            header("location: user.php");
                        }
                    } else{
                        $password_err = "The password you entered was not valid.";
                    }
                }
```

If your username is unique the do like this...

```
                            if($username=='SuperAdmin'){
                                header("location: superadmin.php");
                            }elseif($username=='Admin'){
                                header("location: admin.php");                                
                            }elseif($username=='Others'){
                                header("location: user.php");
                            }
```

Comment: hello sir 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_stmt as array in D:\xammp\htdocs\raisebux\admin\sign-in.php:45 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\xammp\htdocs\raisebux\admin\sign-in.php on line 45

Comment: if($stmt['type_login']=='1'){ //45

Comment: database in a table field name is type_login superadmin 1

Comment: if($stmt['type_login']==1){ //45 also use

Comment: I just give as example . . . See the basics of [mysqli_stmt_fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)

Comment: this link is very hard to code but error location is not understander sir

Comment: Check now my edited answer . . . My kind advice is to learn basics before jump in to work

Comment: i have geting error Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in C:\xampp\htdocs\admin\sign-in.php on line 42

Comment: Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in D:\xammp\htdocs\raisebux\admin\sign-in.php on line 42